# printing mathematical signs not enabled

Tags: sympy

I get an error when I try to call the init_printing function from scipy

```
init_printing(use_latex=True)

TypeError: init_printing() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_latex'
```

How do I correctly enable latex?

```
help(init_printing)

Help on function init_printing in module sympy.interactive.printing:

init_printing(pretty_print=True, order=None, use_unicode=None, wrap_line=None, no_global=False, ip=None)
    Initializes pretty-printer depending on the environment.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably aren't using a new enough version of SymPy. Make sure you are using 0.7.4.1, the latest.